# Output format of command piped to image is incorrect

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Hopefully someone can help.
Here's some backstory:
I needed to format the output of a command, so I could capture the image. This worked for a while, but after an update, or maybe some configuration change, the output is now incorrect.
This is the script I had used to get the output correct:

```
 faketty() {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    script -qfec "$(printf "%q " "$@")" /dev/null                                                                                                                                                                 
  }
```

Here is the code: **Note that the variables are not relevant to this.

```
faketty sudo -u $usr /usr/local/bin/wp --no-color --path="${htmldir}"/ plugin update --all |awk '/Maintenance/,EOF'|tee >(convert -font Courier -pointsize 18 label:@- "${savdir}${url}_${curr_date}.plugins.png")
```

This is a sample of what the output should look like - what it looks like too on the terminal:
[image]

This is what it looks like without the faketty 'function' in the image, while the tty still looks correct.
[image]

This is what the output is like now: - remember the output was correct at some point, now it looks like a hex file?
[image]

I have a feeling something in the script or printf commands, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running one command at a time and looking at the results

Comment: The `convert` command at the end is **ImageMagick**. You may have updated that, so you could try replacing `convert` with `magick`. Or try running `type convert` in your Terminal and getting and checking the full path, then using that full path in your original command.

Comment: You could also check `echo "This is my text" | convert -font Courier -pointsize 18 label:@- dummy.png`

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell, & Mad Physicist.
Looking a bit further, it's actually the piping of the command that messes up the format.
I tried without piping, and the output on the tty is correct. As soon as I pipe something, the format is messed up. I will investigate further, and see what I can come up with....I think then the problem might reside with the wp utlity. Convert, works as expected, when not using wp....

Answer (score 0):

ok, so playing around with different permutations, I managed to come right. To a degree.... Some wp functions will display correctly, but others won't with the below. I think I might need to get hold of the wp-cli team.

```
faketty() {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
script -qfec "$(printf "%s " "$@")" /dev/null   }
```

Note the %p changed to %s